# Proper place to put this functionality?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Just getting started with Ember.js and already have a stupid question! I would like to encapsulate some functionality (that will be called by several different routes). I'm not quite sure where to put it.

The "procedure" should do the following:

1. Call out to an external service (currently a WP REST API but might be a database in the future) to get some data.
2. If the data is an array of JSON objects, extract the first object.
3. Perform some text formatting on the object, specifically call `htmlSafe()` on the HTML-formatted *content* property of the object.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- A helper that performs all of the functionality. It doesn't seem like you can return a promise from a helper, so this doesn't work.
- A util (imported and called from the route's `model()`) that does the data retrieval and a helper that does the data formatting. This works, but seems clumsy?
- A component, which doesn't seem to have a good place to make the AJAX call.

This is a greenfield app so I'm using canary for a bit of future-proofing. I don't want to use triple-curlies for that reason. Here's my code for the middle (working) option:

**app/routes/tos.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import wpJson from '../utils/wp-json';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return wpJson('terms-of-use');
  }
});
```

**app/utils/wp-json.js:**

```
/* global Ember */
export default function wpJson(slug) {
  var url = `/wp-json/posts?type[]=page&filter[name]=${slug}`;
  return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(data => {
    return data.shift();
  });
}
```

**app/templates/tos.hbs:**

```
{{html-safe model.content}}
```

**app/helpers/html-safe.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function htmlSafe([html]) {
  return html.htmlSafe();
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(htmlSafe);
```

In some kind of a perfect world, `app/routes/tos.js` would be empty and `app/templates/tos.hbs` would look more like this:

```
{{wp-foo-bar slug='terms-of-use'}}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting all the logic in a component itself, like this:

```
//app/components/wp-foo-bar/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  remoteData: null,

  loadingData: false,//maybe show spinner depending on this

  fetchRemoteData: function(slug){    
      var url = '/wp-json/posts?type[]=page&filter[name]='+slug;

      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        Ember.$.getJSON(url, function(data){
            resolve(data.shift());
        });
      });
  },

  didInsertElement: function(){
    var slug = this.get('slug');
    this.set('loadingData', true);
    this.fetchRemoteData(slug).then(function(data){
        this.set('remoteData', data);
        this.set('loadingData', false);            
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

And the template for the component would look like:

```
{{html-safe remoteData}}
```

Comment: Thanks Deewendra. I have a few questions. Doesn't getJSON already return a promise? Why are you wrapping it in a new promise?

Comment: Although they are both promises but they are separate implementation of core promise concept. Ember uses RSVP lib for handling promises and in my personal experience, while writing integration testes, things just "work" when wrapping jquery deffered objects/promises within Ember.RSVP promise. But just don't take my word for it, its just personal preference too - you most likely will have no issue if you didn' t wrap things up within RSVP.Promsise

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks again. I don't seem to need the `.bind(this)` at the end of the getJSON callback, or at least it works without it; can you explain why it's necessary and how I would use it with a second callback to handle the failure condition?

Comment: Humm weird it worked without binding! The bind is basically binding the outer context(this which points to the component instance itself) within the closure function provided to 'then' so that when you do this.set('remoteData', data), it is setting remoteData on the component instance and not the promise context that this would have pointed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final solution, based off of Deewandra's solution (which I've marked "correct"). The main difference is the use of [ic-ajax](https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax), which the folks in #emberjs on Freenode strongly recommended for various reasons. I also deleted the `html-safe` helper and moved the `htmlSafe()` function call inside the component.

The only thing I'm still confused about is some intermittent warnings I've been seeing about not setting properties from within the `didInsertElement()` hook. I guess I'll keep an eye on it as Ember.js 2.0 matures and my understanding of the framework continues to improve.

**app/components/wp-get-page.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from '../config/environment';
import ajax from 'ic-ajax';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  slug: null,
  isLoadingData: false,
  remoteData: null,

  didInsertElement() {
    const slug = this.get('slug');
    if (Ember.isEmpty(slug))
      throw new Error('slug not specified in wp-get-page call');

    this.set('isLoadingData', true);
    ajax(`${ENV.APP.WP_API_URL}/posts?type[]=page&filter[name]=${slug}`)
      .then(data => {
        if (Ember.isEmpty(data))
          throw new Error('no data from wp-json');

        if (Ember.isArray(data) && data.length === 1)
          data = data.shift();

        this.set('remoteData', {
          title: data.title,
          content: data.content.htmlSafe()
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.set('remoteData', {
          title: 'Sorry',
          content: 'Unable to retrieve page contents! Please try again later.'
        });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.set('isLoadingData', false);
      });
  }
});
```